# Return DOM elements based on array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

As a challenge, I am trying to create a JavaScript selection engine i.e. a JavaScript function that will return DOM elements given a CSS selector.

I cant use document.querySelector/document.querySelectorAll.

I am currently creating a object of the parameter, but am now stuck. I now need to loop through every element on the page, and if it matches my tag, or class/id, push that element to an array.

```
$("div") //Should return 2 DIVs

$("img.some_class") //Should return 1 IMG

$("#some_id") //Should return 1 DIV 

$(".some_class") //Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG
```

```js
function $ (selector) { 

 var elements =[];

 var pageTags =[];

 var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

 //splits selector
 var arg = parse(selector);

 function parse(subselector) {
   var obj = {tags:[], classes:[], ids:[], attrs:[]};
   subselector.split(/(?=\.)|(?=#)|(?=\[)/).forEach(function(token){
      switch (token[0]) {
        case '#':
           obj.ids.push(token.slice(1));
          break;
        case '.':
           obj.classes.push(token.slice(1));
          break;
        case '[':
           obj.attrs.push(token.slice(1,-1).split('='));
          break;
        default :
           obj.tags.push(token);
          break;
      }
    });
    return obj;
 }

 console.log(arg);


 for (var item of all) {

  //gets tagname of all page elements
  var element = item.tagName.toLowerCase();

  console.log(element);
  //if argument contains DOM element
  if (arg.indexOf(element) !== -1) {

   var x = document.getElementsByTagName(element);
   
   for (var test of x) {
    elements.push(test);
   }

  }

 }

 return elements;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Answer.js"></script>
    <script src="Test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="test$()">
    <div></div>
    <div id="some_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></div>
    <img id="some_other_id" class="some_class some_other_class"></img>
    <input type="text">
  </body>
</html>
```

Please any help on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: Only for this one time I'd say "use jquery"

Comment: Challenge is to use vanilla JavaScript :(

Comment: You don't know or don't want to use `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: That’s the challenge @Mamun, I can’t use it or jQuery.

Comment: This sounds like homework. It's homework isn't it? It's definitely homework.

Comment: [sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/)

Comment: It has to be vanilla JavaScript, no frameworks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa6wvre4/14/).
There would be many many more combinations of course ...

I limited the test cases to the html example you provided.

```
function _select(attrValues, tagFilter, cssSel) {

  var results = [];
  //var value = selector.slice(1);
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName(tagFilter);
  //look for an id attribute
  if (cssSel === '#') {
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      if (all[i].id === attrValues) {
        results.push(all[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof attrValues === 'string') {
      for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i].classList.contains(attrValues)) {
            results.push(all[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
        //multiple selector classes
      var found = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < attrValues.length; j++) {
          if (all[i].classList.contains(attrValues[j])) {
            found += 1;
            if (found === attrValues.length) {
              results.push(all[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

function $(selector) {

  var cssSel = selector.charAt(0);
  var cssSelectors = ['.', '#'];

  if (cssSel === cssSelectors[0] || cssSel === cssSelectors[1]) {
    //direct selector
    var attrValue = selector.slice(1),
      tagFilter = '*';
    return _select(attrValue, tagFilter, cssSel)
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < cssSelectors.length; i++) {
      var tokens = selector.split(cssSelectors[i]);
      if (tokens.length > 1 && tokens[0] !== "") {
        //nested selector
        var tagFilter = tokens[0], //the first of the array should be the tagname ,because the case of the cssSelector at charAt(0) should have been caught in the if at the beginning.
          attrValue = tokens.slice(1); //the rest of the array are selector values
        return _select(attrValue, tagFilter, cssSel)
      }
    }
  }
  return document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
}

//TEST cases

var results = $("div")
console.log('Should return 2 DIVs')
for ( var e of results){
    console.log(e)
}

var results = $(".some_class")
console.log('Should return 1 DIV and 1 IMG')
for ( var e of results){
    console.log(e)
}

var results = $("#some_id")
console.log('Should return 1 DIV ')
for ( var e of results){
    console.log(e)
}

var results = $("img.some_class")
console.log('Should return 1 IMG')
for ( var e of results){
    console.log(e)
}

var results = $("div.some_class.some_other_class")
console.log('Should return 1 div')
for ( var e of results){
    console.log(e)
}
```